# How to add if and date in google script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I am a beginner with code script. Can you help me with my function please?

I have bot and he send data to google sheets, he send name, phone, date and method of communication. I need that google sheets write in column C date when was get the data from phone. I only now get the date, but in addition i need if - else. "If the column C is not empty send their date since last request", in addition i think I need to add method forEach and method so that the data is updated automatically when phone is received. For this I think need trigger "doGet(e)" from google documentation
[(spread sheet image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tYxO.png)
Data get from webhook
Here is my code:

```
function getDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numbers = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B1000")
  let dateGoogle = new Date();
  var rr = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1:C1000").setValue(dateGoogle);
}
```

Comment: Checking if I understand it right: ColA gets Name, ColB gets phone, ColC gets the date. If the date is empty, then grab that person or phone number's last date found above...?

Comment: _I have the bot and he sends data to google sheets_ -- how the bot looks like? As far as I can tell the most obvious way would be to modify the code of the bot, to add one more field (date) into its return data.

Comment: santoInit, yes. Thats right.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, Это бот в bothelp и необходимо 4 параметра, Имя Номер Дата последнего обращения и Метод связи. Все предлагает конструктор bothelp, однако из-за ограничения тарифа, дата обращения не может быть реализована через конструктор и я прибегнул к скрипту на google script. Наверное это должно быть как условие "если пришел getPost запрос", то в колонке C нужно написать  дату, когда пришло

Comment: @santosOnit, No my bot didnt get the date and thats a problem that i need to solve. I only have parameters name phone and method of communication

Comment: Well. As a workaround you can add the time driven trigger to the sheet that will fire every hour (or every minute, or several hours?) it will check the sheet and fills all empty cells in C column with current date (for rows that have data in B column). Not sure if it's an optimal solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case. If you're able to run the function `getDate()` and all you need is to make it to fill cells in C column only for rows that have filled cells in B column it can be done this way:

```
function getDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getData();
  var data = range.getValues();
  let dateGoogle = new Date();

  data.forEach(x => x[2] = (x[2] == '' && x[1] != '') ? dateGoogle : x[2]);
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

If you ask how to run the function `getData()` via `doGet()` I have no answer.

Comment: Why we use doGet(), bot not doPost()?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in html + Google App Script interaction. Perhaps I can fix some half-working code, but I can't answer why there should be `doGet()` instead of `doPost()` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a doPost()

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.postData.contents);
  Logger.log(e.postData.type);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let row = [];
  ['name','phone','date','method'].forEach(k => row.push(data[k]));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row))
  sh.appendRow(row);
}
```

Below function Simulate what I imagine the bot can do to send data.  This one is sending the data as JSON.

```
function sendData(obj) {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  const params={"contentType":"application/json","payload":JSON.stringify(obj),"muteHttpExceptions":true,"method":"post","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
}

function saveMyData() {
  sendData({name:"name",phone:"phone1",date:"date1",method:"post"});
}
```

You will have to Deploy the doPost(e) as a webapp.